# Clustered index for foreign key column

Tags: mysql, indexing, primary-key

Consider the following example of a messaging system:

```
create table chat_group
(
    id           int auto_increment primary key,
    title        varchar(100)         not null,
    date_created date                 not null
)


create table chat_message
(
    id                int auto_increment,
    user_id           int                  not null,
    chat_group_id     int                  not null,
    message           text charset utf8mb4 not null,
    date_created      datetime             not null
)
```

Now I see that the most common request for the `chat_message` table is `SELECT * FROM chat_message where chat_group_id = ?`. So my idea is to put a clustered index on `chat_group_id` column so the chat messages will be organized by groups on the disk.

But in MySQL it requires PRIMARY KEY(which actually is a clustered index) to be unique, so what is the solution here? What clustered index do I make for the given situation.

Comment: Just use an ordinary index for this, it doesn't have to be a clustered index.

Comment: @Barmar what's the use of the clustered index then? If it's always has to be an id column

Comment: It's not something you "use", it's just a description of the index used internally to identify each row uniquely. So it's the fastest type of index.

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry but I don't see your point. as I see in the docs clustered index is actually a way of organizing data on the disk, while non-clustered index is a separate structure. isn't it a smart idea to keep messages that likely to be requested all together close one to another rather than keep them separate

Comment: There's no way to "put a clustered index" on a specific column. The clustered index is created automatically, it's not something you do. It defaults to the primary key, or something other unique index if there's no primary key. There's no way for you to create it explicitly.

Comment: Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "you can have your cake and eat it, too":

```
PRIMARY KEY(chat_group_id, id),
INDEX(id)
```

The PK provides "clustering" by the group; this is likely to speed up your main queries.  Including `id` makes it UNIQUE, which is a requirement (in MySQL) for the PK.

The secondary `INDEX(id)` is the minimum needed to keep `AUTO_INCREMENT` happy -- namely having *some* index *starting with* the id.

Comment: This allows duplicate `id`, because a composite key only has to be unique in the combination of columns, not each column by itself.

Comment: probably he meant setting a `UNIQUE` constraint on the id column definition

Comment: @LuninRoman - I consider the uniqueness constraint to be _usually_ unnecessary.  If you only let `AUTO_INCREMENT` generate new values, you won't get any dups.  Otherwise, yes, you _could_ create a dup id by explicitly setting id.  (That is an abuse that should/could be avoided.)